Snowflake - dynamic "copy into" across different stages
I am trying to create a procedure in Snowflake that will dynamically copy files from different external stages in S3 into a table. Please see the procedure below:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE manual_adjustments.validate_errors()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE  SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

BEGIN
COPY INTO manual_adjustments.validate_errors
FROM @manual_adjustments.XXX
on_error = 'CONTINUE';
insert into manual_adjustments.stage_logs 
SELECT *, current_date, ''  FROM TABLE(VALIDATE(manual_adjustments.validate_errors, JOB_ID => '_last'));
END;
$$;

I want to be able to pass a stage name as an argument to the procedure so it dynamically replaces the "XXX" and copies the files from that stage. For example if I run the procedure as below:
CALL manual_adjustments.validate_errors(stage1);

The above should run a copy into "manual_adjustments.validate_errors" from stage "@manual_adjustments.stage1" and so forth.
Any suggestions?

You can build and/or manipulate a string, for example using the replace function, that gets you the SQL you want to run. Once you have that, you can use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command inside your SQL Script SP.
